# JQuery File Upload 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, jquery, upload

I've been stuck on this for about a week and I just seem to be going around in circles.

The problem is receiving a 500 Internal Server error when uploading files. I've posted around a few forums but help is extremely limited due to me running a Windows Server.

So what have I done so far?

1. Checked, double checked, triple checked the PHP.INI file to make sure I have all the correct attributes set:

   ```
    max_execution_time   600
    max_input_time   600
    memory_limit   128M
    post_max_size     50M
    upload_max_filesize   50M
   ```
2. Checked over the script and decided to test a few different scripts from various sources W3Schools, PHP.net etc same problem.
3. Upgraded PHP5 to PHP5.3 same issue
4. Tried to implement it using the JQuery_File_Upload API and I got unstable results. Rarely it would upload >10MB files and almost always threw out a Internal Server Error
5. Checked the error log. I checked it but nothing out of the ordinary in there and last write was a few days ago so I added a custom log and again, nothing being written to it.

What else can I do? I'm running a dedicated server, Windows 2008, Plesk.

Please help!

Thanks.

Comment: Have you got the display_errors, log_errors directives in the PHP.ini file correct? You will want to log errors to the correct error log. 500 errors should be logged somewhere if logging is enabled.

Comment: Does phpinfo() run properly?

Comment: Does it work on local?

Comment: display_errors On. Adding errors to a custom log for debugging and nothing out of the ordinary is appearing in there, just a few SQL errors from a different script.

Comment: Just tried something different. I've been doing it via a webpage, but if I do it via remote connection on the server it uploads perfectly fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Found something in the log: 2013-05-23 09:18:22 W3SVC12 SERVER SERVERIP POST /account/test/server/php/ - 80 - IP HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.31+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/26.0.1410.64+Safari/537.31 PHPSESSID=d828b568c8c122e45b4b376ff1287a74;+__atuvc=0%7C13%2C0%7C14%2C0%7C15%2C0%7C16%2C18%7C17;+__utma=11234787.1386610922.1366208206.1369234912.1369298491.64;+__utmc=11234787;+__utmz=11234787.1366208206.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none) http://www.site.co.uk/account/test/ www.site.co.uk 500 0 2147500037 1572 11233100 121353

Comment: <<<BUMP>>> can anybody help me with this, I'm still getting nowhere other than figuring out that it is 100% a PHP issue and most probably either the file size limit or the moving of the file from the TEMP dir.

Comment: i think it is a problem with the htaccess provided in the server directory

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by checking the /var/log/apache2/error_log files. Saw something there that indicated that a.htaccess file was being read, so i went to that dir and opened the .htaccess file:
server/php/files/.htaccess

Then commented out the below line by putting a hash in front of it:
Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"

Then browsed to the directory and it worked fine.

Comment: OP does state I'm on a Windows server. I resolved the issue anyway, apparently Plesk, Windows & PHP don't mix very well.... there were about 15 different php.ini that needed configuring. The confusion was with PHP Manager in IIS which can get totally ignored by php.ini so why they even bother to put it there anyway is beyond me!

Comment: yeah maybe plesk is the problem than i ran into the same problem with an ubuntu Plesk server

Comment: Or better still just removed the Htaccess file and it worked in my case